# How to animate marker from one position to another?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, maps

I need to animate marker position from one coordinate to another. When I change the position via `copyWith` it's already animated but doesn't let to set the animation duration.

And looks like there's no built in method for this purpose yet. What would be the best way to do it manually?

Comment: Use Matrix4Translation with animation

Comment: did you get a way to do this?